# How to move files and folders to Trash programmatically on macOS?

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, recycle-bin

All I can find on this topic is mentions of `FSMoveObjectToTrashSync` function, which is now [deprecated and no alternative is listed for it](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/1566651-fsmoveobjecttotrashsync).

How to do it from C or Objective-C code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Properly move an object to the Trash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34034638/properly-move-an-object-to-the-trash)

Comment: I have no idea, but Google says: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider/nsfileproviderextension/2879524-trashitem

Comment: @jxh: Thanks. This is different from the answer to the suggested dupe.

Comment: @jxh are `FileProvider` and  `trashItem(withIdentifier:completionHandler:)` available on macOS?

Comment: @Willeke: As stated earlier, I have no idea. But, [@n3wb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51486633/315052)s answer seems to suggest a similar API is available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use NSFileManager:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager

> - trashItemAtURL:resultingItemURL:error:
>     Moves an item to the trash.

Answer (score 2):

In C, you can use AppleScript to move files to the trash. Here's a simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PATH "/tmp/"
#define NAME "delete-me.txt"

int main() {
    int status;

    /* Create a file */
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen(PATH NAME, "w");
    if (!f) {
        fputs("Can't create file " PATH NAME "\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    fputs("I love trash\n", f);
    fclose(f);

    /* Now put it in the trash */
    status = system(
        "osascript -e 'set theFile to POSIX file \"" PATH NAME "\"' "
                  "-e 'tell application \"Finder\"' "
                      "-e 'delete theFile' "
                  "-e 'end tell' "
                  ">/dev/null"
    );

    if (status == 0) {
        puts("Look in the trash folder for a file called " NAME);
    }
    else {
        puts("Something went wrong. Unable to delete " PATH NAME);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A few notes:

- Multi-line scripts have to be sent as multiple `-e` command line options.
- Since `osascript` insists on printing status messages to the command line console, I've redirected its output to `/dev/null`. **But,** if a file of the same name already exists in the trash, then the deleted file will be renamed. If you need to know this name, you'll have to use `popen()` instead of `system()` and parse the return string from `osascript`.