# How to Trash items that are not owned by the current user, the same way the Finder does?

Tags: macos, filesystems, nsfilemanager, nsworkspace

I am writing a tool that offers the option to trash selected items (files, folders). Usually, I'd call `-[NSFileManager trashItemAtURL:...]` for each of those items, as it's also explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51484900) and in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34034638) SO question.

However, ***these do not work when trying to delete files from a directory owned by a different user, such as root***. My tool shall offer the same option as the Finder in this case, i.e. ask the user to authorize the operation by providing the credentials of an Admin user, and then my app would move the items to the Trash like the Finder does.

I've tried solving this by using a privileged helper, as outline by the `EvenBetterAuthorizationSample` example code, using `launchd`, `SMJobBless` and XPC Services.

The problem with that is, however, that the privileged helper runs as the root user, without knowledge of the current user my app runs under. The result is that, when it trashes a file, ***it ends up in the root user's Trash folder and not, as the Finder would do it, in the user's Trash folder.***

How do I solve this, i.e. **how do I move items not owned by the user to the current user's trash instead of the root user's Trash?**

Is there some trick I can use that would let me keep using one of the existing trash oder recycle functions?

Doing the move myself is not going to work properly because for **Put Back** to work, the Trash's `.DS_Store` file would need to be updated, and there's no API for that, AFAIK.

Comment: There's a Unix command geteuid() I think, to get the "effective" user instead of the user you're running as. If your daemon is launched per-user, I'd expect that to be set. Have you tried that?

Comment: You mean getuid - geteuid always is 0 for such a daemon, but getuid did indeed return the user's id. I did try that when launching my helper via `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges`: In 10.15 (b1) getuid returns the root user and not the current user as it used to before. I will test if that is different with a user-specific launchd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have *almost* found a solution:

#### Analysis

When the helper is run, e.g. from `launchd`, or via `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges` (under macOS 10.15), it may be running as root, with no knowledge of the logged-in user, hence it cannot determine the user's Trash folder.

Oddly, the Environment variables (see `man env`) may even show the current user's name and home dir, yet the *real user id*, which one can query with `getuid()`, will return 0 (root), which also results in `NSUserName()`and `NSHomeDirectory()` returning the root user's information. And it appears that `trashItemAtURL` and related functions rely on `NSHomeDirectory()` to determine the Trash folder location.

#### Half-working solution

Fortunately, there is a way to change the *real user id*, with `setreuid`.

Therefore, in my testing, when I call `setreuid (501, 0)` (501 being the uid of the currently logged-in user), then `trashItemAtURL` does move the file to the user's Trash folder, indeed, along with automatic renaming where necessary.

However, this does *not* make the **Put Back** work, the way it would when trashing the same file using the Finder.

#### Making Put Back work

Looks like the reason for **Put Back** not working comes from a deeper issue: It appears to be a long-standing bug in the macOS framework, see [this bug report](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5063396789583872).

Which basically means: This is the best we can get out of it until Apple fixes the underlying bug.

The only working alternative to make **Put Back** work is to ask the Finder to trash the items using AppleEvents / AppleScript.