# How to programmatically uninstall App that install DriverKit system extension

Tags: macos, driverkit, macos-system-extension

I have an app that installs a DriverKit system extension when it launches.

If I then drag this app to the Bin from `/Applications` then I am prompted about that the app also manages a system extension and that the system extension also will be removed.

I would like to have an uninstaller that removes the app. I have tried to remove the app in the uninstaller with `rm -rf`, but then the system extension is not removed.

I have also tried the [`trash`](https://github.com/ali-rantakari/trash) terminal utility (can be installed with `brew install trash`) to check if something similar could be used from the uninstaller, but without luck.

Is there a way to programmatically remove an app and also the system extension that the app installs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question! I don't have a fully baked answer, but enough suggestions to try that they won't fit in a comment, so here goes anyway:

- Try using Cocoa APIs for "trashing" files. [This answer gives a good rundown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34034942/48660). I don't know how this will cope with the system extension confirmation though.
- If you definitely *want* to pop up the confirmation dialog, using AppleScript to tell the Finder to delete the file is a great approach. I can confirm the [solution given in this answer works](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/310084/24746) but it *will* show the confirmation dialog, which may or may not be what you want.
- You can uninstall a system extension (including a dext) using the `systemextensionsctl uninstall` command. Unfortunately, this will always pop up an *authentication* dialog, even if you run it with root privileges. But depending on what you're doing, that might be preferable to the above.

Comment: AppleScript solution works great. The confirmation dialog appears but that is ok.